# How can you analyse all reviews from a steam game including both, other and steam purchases?

Tags: json, steam, review, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

I am trying to analyse reviews posted on Steam according to whether they are purchased on Steam or not. Therefore, I am trying to collect all reviews from a game on Steam. I already tried this method:

`http://store.steampowered.com/appreviews/278620?json=1&start_offset=0`
`http://store.steampowered.com/appreviews/278620?json=1&start_offset=20`
`http://store.steampowered.com/appreviews/278620?json=1&start_offset=40`

However, this method does not return all reviews written on the Steam page of the game. Furthermore, it only returns positive reviews and does not return games not purchased on Steam.

Therefore, I tried reviewing them manually, but if I visit a game page on Steam (http://store.steampowered.com/app/278620/TinyKeep/), scroll down and click on browse all reviews, it also does not display all reviews. Furthermore, it does not indicate whether games are purchased on Steam or not.

Is there a way to get all reviews on a game, including whether it was purchased on Steam or not?